# How to make an authentication API using python

Tags: python, http, raspberry-pi, request

I would like to make an API, like [this](https://www.mecallapi.com/) using Python on my Raspberry Pi 4.
I have a website with a login screen, where if I press the login button, it sends a request containing the username and the password, and the API returns back if its good or not.

I have very little experience with this, so I don't know if its possible for me.

Comment: It is possible but, why would you want to make an API for that when there are more efficient ways!

Comment: What would be a more efficient way?

Comment: If you work with any framwork, it has a login system and `form` for submission and you can use them for more security, etc. besides, login API is usually used for applications and mobile apps.